# Запись массива из textarea в MySQL

Tags: php, sql

есть следующий код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" >
</head>

<body>
  <form action="string_load_sql.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

string_load_sql.php файл

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "msg_oper";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST["text"])) {
    $text   = explode("\n",(trim($_POST["text"])));
       foreach ( $text AS $text_string ) {
               $sql = "INSERT INTO `oper_find` (num) VALUES ('".$text_string."')";
      echo($text_string);
    }
  }
 
  for($x=0;$x<100;$x++)
  {
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "OK!";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
  }
$conn->close();
?>
```

данные ведение в textarea выводятся построчно "echo($text)". Как их записать в базу данных sql, так же построчно?

Comment: explode $_POST['text'] по переводам строк даст вам массив строк текста, берите его и записывайте

Comment: $text   = nl2br($_POST['text']); это уже переводить в массив. Вопрос в том, как его записать?

Comment: делаете цикл по массиву и пишите? в каком месте не получается?

Comment: nl2br не делает массив, он заменяет переводы строк на `<br />`.  Что вы называете массивом?

Comment: вы правы. добавил:
`$text   = explode("\r", ($_POST["text"]) );`
`$sql = "INSERT INTO `oper_find` (num) VALUES ('".$text."')";`
выдает ошибку :
Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\

Comment: так вы хотите каждую строку отдельной записью БД или все кучей?

Comment: да, каждую строку отдельной записью

Comment: так по одной строке и записывайте в цикле

Comment: где посмотреть пример?

Comment: пример цикла ? foreac($text as $line) {  // добавляем строку, как вы добавляли $text }

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["text"])) {
    $text   = explode("\r", ($_POST["text"]));
    foreach ($text AS $line) { 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `oper_find` (num) VALUES ('".$line."')";
      echo($line);
}
  }`
не помогло

Comment: чему не помогло, вы не выполняете ни одного запроса, посмотрите примеры работы с БД

Comment: что значит "ни одного запроса"?

Comment: в базу внесит только последнюю запись. например:
123
321
545
879

в базу внесет только 879

Comment: `$sql =` - это не выполнение запроса. какой-нить execute должен быть

Comment: можете поточнее?

Comment: Приведенный вами код не может записать ни одной строки. Покажите как одну строку "внесли в базу"

Comment: добавил полностью код, который записывает  в базу только  одно, последнее значение

Comment: весь вот этот if ... с query подставьте внутрь цикла вместо или рядом с echo

Comment: вставил цикл но сейчас кратно (100) все также вносит  100 раз только  последюю строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "msg_oper";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_POST["text"])) {
    $text   = explode("\n",(trim($_POST["text"])));
        for($x=0;$x<1;$x++)
        {
            foreach ( $text AS $text_string ) {
               $sql = "INSERT INTO `oper_find` (num) VALUES ('".$text_string."')";
      echo($text_string);
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "OK!";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    }
    }
  }
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: спасибо. то что надо.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(explode("\n",$_POST['text']) as $str){
//тут пишем $str в БД
}
```

Comment: так не работает